# Shortest way to find the focused point in an auto focus algorithm

Tags: image-processing, graph-algorithm, autofocus

I'm writing an algorithm for auto focus. For that I'm using a stepper motor which has 3318 steps for focus.

To find the focus, after every frame from the camera I'm taking the statistics and performing some calculation which results in a numeric value, i.e. focus value (`fv`). So the motor step where I get the highest `fv` is where my image is highest focused.

Right now, I am traversing through all the points to find the maximum `fv` and it's working but taking too long; about 15 secs.

Is there any algorithm I can use to reduce the no. of steps and minimize the time to find the focused point?

Answer (score 0):

If you assume there is:

1. A *single* global maximum sharpness score;
2. No local maxima

Then your focus function should be relatively smooth.

In this case, you can do a search that is faster than linear.
Basically start somewhere and start rolling downhill.

You can use e.g. the [Golden section search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden-section_search) or by calculating the local change (derivatives) use the Newton (rolling down hill) or Conjugate gradient (jumping downhill) methods.

Answer (score 0):

First, find out what exactly your bottleneck is:

- time to take a frame
- time to move the stepper motor to a specific position
- time to process the frame and get a focus function value

Then learn something about the functional dependence of your focus function on the focus position in general (for your samples).

- Is it smooth or bumpy (noisy)?
- Is it wide (very flat maximum) or is it narrow (very steep, small maximum)?
- Is it approximately quadratic?

Most probably there is not much noise, the maximum is rather wide and approximately quadratic.

Then [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) or the [Levenberg-Marquardt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenberg%E2%80%93Marquardt_algorithm) fitting algorithm would converge in a few iterations.

However they only find local optima as well as the Golden search mentioned in the answer by [Adi Shavit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41722088/1536976).

When noise is a problem, I recommend a kind of robust, zoom in approach:

- Measure 10 frames over the whole range (332 steps away each)
- Smooth the resulting 10 values slightly if there is noise present
- Take the position of the best frame
- Measure 20 frames over a range of [-330,330] steps around this best frame with a step size of 33 steps per frame
- Smooth the resulting 20 values slightly if there is noise present
- Take the position of the best frame
- Measure 10 frames over a range of [-15, 15] steps around this best frame with a step size of 3 steps per frame
- Smooth the resulting 10 values slightly if there is noise present
- Take the best frame and measure one frame above and below
- Take the best frame, it's the focus position

This needs 10+20+10+2=32 frames recorded and may therefore present an approximately 100 times speedup compared to taking 3318 frames or (0.15s instead of 15s) if taking the frames is the crucial part and not moving the stepper motor.